# Entity reference use other fields in view modes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I have a student books products in drupal 7 which they have a companion teacher's book product. I want to make a view mode that presents the student book (product display) along with an entity reference to teacher's book which is also a book product. 
Thing is that I can display the either id, title, or rendered entity but not other entity fields. I want to display is this:

Student's ISDN:   ***_*__*_*__**

Teacher's's ISDN: ***_*__*_*__**

... Other product fields (Student) ...

I 've tried several modules like display suite but nothing, can you please help? what I 'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
  // Initial weight
  $weight = 2;
  // Student's book entity
  $student_book_entity = $node->field_student_book[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['entity'];

  // Get Student's book ISBN and alter some attributes
  $student_isbn_field = array_merge(field_view_field('commerce_product', $student_book_entity, 'field_book_isbn'), array(
      '#field_name' => 'field_students_book_isbn',
      '#title' => t('Student\'s Book ISBN'),
      '#weight' => $weight++,
    )
  );
  $node->content['field_students_book_isbn'] = $student_isbn_field;

  // Teacher's book entity
  $teachers_book_entity = $node->field_teacher_book[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['entity'];

  // Get Teacher's book ISBN and alter some attributes
  $teacher_isbn_field = array_merge(field_view_field('commerce_product', $teachers_book_entity, 'field_book_isbn'), array(
      '#field_name' => 'field_teachers_book_isbn',
      '#title' => t('Teacher\'s Book ISBN'),
      '#weight' => $weight++,
    )
  );
  $node->content['field_teachers_book_isbn'] = $teacher_isbn_field;
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to create a new node template for your content type. E.g: `node--student.tpl.php`, then use the following code as example:

```
$referenced_node = node_load($node->field_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['target_id']);
print node_view($referenced_node, "teaser");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use views, I just use view mode for displaying a single node.

Comment: Not sure if node_load works with entities, I am  trying to do it through module using hook_node_view()

Comment: This code retrieves the `nid` from the referencing node, then uses `node_load` to load the node object. Nothing strange :)

Comment: I use entity reference. I get entity this way $teachers_book_entity = $node->field_teacher_book[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['entity']; Also I don't need to print a view mode (teaser) just a field: ISBN.

Comment: If you load the entire teacher book node using the node_load method above, you should then be able to get to any of the fields...